# Is a ball which passes behind the batsman and over the stumps a wide?

Tags: rules, cricket

If the ball goes behind the batsman, and then goes over the wickets without touching the wickets, then is it a wide ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this would not a wide ball. A wide is defined by [Law 25](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-25-wide-ball/):

> If the bowler bowls a ball [...] the umpire shall adjudge it a Wide if [...] in his opinion the ball passes wide of the striker where he is **and which also would have passed wide of him standing in a normal guard position**.

(my emphasis). A striker standing in a normal guard position would be able to play a ball which passes over the stumps, so this is not a wide.

Comment: Additionally any ball in one day cricket that passes over the stumps will not be called wide